# Database for C# applications in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am planning a Visual Studio 2013 C# app. When I need to add a local database, the option that I have is a `.mdf` file to be added.

My question is: how to I deploy this application? Should I have SQL Server Express on the client machine? So how do I bundle SQL Server Express with the setup?

Comment: yes, you need to install SQL Server Express in order to restore .mdf file. but usually it has two files to attach the database to SQL Server .mdf and .ldf files

Comment: If you don't need a sharing database in a network, simply use `Sqlite` or `SqlCE`. You don't need to install anything for `Sqlite`. But you will have to install a simple little engine to run SqlCE.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience you need to install a SQL Server on your platform. The reason is for them to read the .mdf and ldf file.

for your deployment process you need to place the database and log files to a location and change your connection string (.config file).

Hope that helps. :)